# Linker error for a template method

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I'm having problems with the linker.

It gives me the following error:

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `bool Polis :: deleteEdifice <Mine> (int) '
```

The prototype is declared as follows:

```
template <typename T> bool deleteEdifice(int);
```

deleteEdifice is empty, that does not do anything for now but it does not work.

The call to the prototype is:

```
obj->deleteEdifice<Mine>(3);
```

I also tried to do:

```
obj->template deleteEdifice<Mine>(3);
```

Print the following error:

```
`template' (as a disambiguator) is only allowed within templates
```

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: "deleteEdifice is empty, that does not do anything for now but it does not work." Please clarify. What does it mean? Is there any code that relates to this sentence? Can you show it?

Comment: You have to define the template in the header file, not just declare it. `template <typename T> bool deleteEdifice(int){}`

Comment: Is the definition of `deleteEdifice` in a .cpp file?

Comment: Sorry. I deleted my comment. I'll post an answer, but faranwath asked a very good question. The definition of templates should be in h files.

Comment: Based on the way he said, "The prototype is declared as follows" I believe that he defined it in a cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
template <typename T> bool deleteEdifice(int);
```

does not mean it is empty, it means it is undefined like the error `[Linker error] undefined reference`

This

```
template <typename T> bool deleteEdifice(int) { return false; }
```

is empty

Comment: I did the same thing, it gives me the following error: [Linker error] undefined reference to `bool Polis :: deleteEdifice <Mine> (int) '

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having problems with the linker. It gives me the following error:
>   [Linker error] undefined reference to `bool Polis :: deleteEdifice
>    (int) '

I'm assuming your code looks like this:

```
//.h file
class Polis
{
  public:
    //...constructor etc...
    template <class T>
    bool deleteEdifice( int );
};
```

**Also .h file**

```
//, where definition of template is visible at 
// point of instantiation - remember, template is instantiated
// when used (in compilation unit where used), therefore its 
// definition has to be visible in the scope where used. It is
// only instantiated when used... If it's definition is not 
// available at the point of instantiation (where called for 
// a function template), it is never 
// compiled.

template <class T>
bool Polis::deleteEdifice( int )
{
  //Implementation here...
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing, it gives me the following error: [Linker error] undefined reference to `bool Polis :: deleteEdifice <Mine> (int) '